# tikzcd arrow with array in label

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrays, ampersand

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\left< x, y \right>
\ar[r, "{{\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)}}"]
&
\left< z,w \right>
\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

generates the error message

```
Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@let@token ...{{\left ( \begin {array}{cc} a &
                                               b \\ c & d \end {array} \...
```

The problem is discussed in section 3.4 of the tikzcd manual at
http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf.   One solution is as follows:   use the "ampersand replacement" option to tikzcd to use a different character for separating nodes in the commutative diagram.  This leaves the ampersand available for use in the array in the arrow's label.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\left< x, y \right>
\ar[r, "{{\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)}}"]
\&                   %% Note replacement of & by \& here
\left< z,w \right>
\\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Comment: Done.   With solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, (per section 3.4 of http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf):

add option to tikzcd, viz

```
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
```

An example is in the text cited.